# Insert json in postgres via bash script using kubectl

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm trying to update a field in one of my table using bash script. I'm trying to insert json values inside of this field in postgress. The field type is 'text'. Here is  the query which I try to execute:

```
TOKEN="${ENV_TOKEN}"
kubectl exec -it postgres-d5b5794-7fxxm -n eclipse-che -- bash -c "psql keycloak -c UPDATE federated_identity SET token ={"access_token":"'$TOKEN'","expires_in":86400,"scope":"user:full","token_type":"Bearer"}  WHERE federated_username = 'admin'"
```

After executing this code I got the following error:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "SET" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "token" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "=access_token:sha256~g1KaHT3-RSa2G1oPfDboc7jI90OLy67VQ4mJsVjFYZw" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "=expires_in:86400" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "=scope:user:full" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "=token_type:Bearer" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "WHERE" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "federated_username" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "=" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "admin" ignored
psql: FATAL:  role "federated_identity" does not exist
command terminated with exit code 2
```

I've tried everyting to avoid the quotes but nothing works...

Can someone please help me to make work this query?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to add JSON object but here is working syntax for CREATE & INSERT with kubectl. Best way would be to put your SQL statement within file to avoid the pain of ensuring double/sungle quotes are escaped properly or not. Escaping quotes becomes very complex with few values only. My recommendation is to use *.sql file with all your SQL statements.

**SQL file execution with kubectl**

```
kubectl exec -i <pod-name> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -f /tmp/create.sql"
```

**Create table**

```
kubectl exec -i <pod-name> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE TABLE account1 (user_id INT PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);\""
```

**Insert record into table**

```
kubectl exec -i <pod-name> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -c \"INSERT INTO account1 VALUES (1, 'dummyuser', 'dummypassword', 'dummy@gmail.com');\""
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the string after `psql -c` should be quoted as a single argument, but you are already using both single and double quotes in it, so attempting to just add more quotes is not sufficient.

Because you can't easily escape single quotes within single quotes, the simplest solution is probably to add double quotes around the string, and backslash-escape any existing double quotes within.

```sh
kubectl exec -it postgres-d5b5794-7fxxm -n eclipse-che -- bash -c "psql keycloak -c \"UPDATE federated_identity SET token ={\\\"access_token\\\":\\\"'$TOKEN'\\\",\\\"expires_in\\\":86400,\\\"scope\\\":\\\"user:full\\\",\\\"token_type\\\":\\\"Bearer\\\"}  WHERE federated_username = 'admin'\""
```

Because I had to guess which quotes belong to which level of nested string, this probably needs some adjustments. Try to add `printf '%s\\n'` in front of `psql keycloak` to have the container simply print out the result.  I would imagine that you might need more quoting around the JSON string, but I'm not familiar enough with `psql` to guess what that should look like. Also, the quoting around `$TOKEN` looks wrong (and it seems rather pointless to copy `$ENV_TOKEN` to a new identical variable which you do not change at all).

If `kubectl exec -it postgres-d5b5794-7fxxm -n eclipse-che -- bash` lets you read from standard input (not in a place where I can check that) you might be able to use a here document instead:

```sh
kubectl exec -it postgres-d5b5794-7fxxm -n eclipse-che -- bash <<____
psql keycloak -c "UPDATE federated_identity SET token ={\"access_token\":\"'$TOKEN'\",\"expires_in\":86400,\"scope\":\"user:full\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\"}  WHERE federated_username = 'admin';"
____
```

Again, I had to guess some things.  If you can't get this to work, perhaps update your question to explain in more detail what the code is expected to do.